# javascript ui width from child elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

If you have an unordered list full of LI elements, all the same width, how can you calculate the width of the UL so you can set it the right width to accomidate all the LI elements on a single line?

Answer (score 1):

I was getting lazy here's the answer:

```
var width = 0;
$('div.sliderGallery ul li').each(function() {
width += $(this).outerWidth( true );
            });
$('div.sliderGallery ul').css('width', width);
```